# Make my connection string to SQL Server database using a static IP secure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm using the following connection string to connect from my windows app to SQL Server database that located on a WebSite:

```
dim constr As String = "data source=IPAdresse;initial catalog=mydb;User Id=username;Password=pwd
```

is this way of connection secure?

Should I use (https://) before writing the IP address in the connection string?

If not, how can I make my connection secure and unavailable to hackers?

Comment: `how can I make my connection secure and unavailable to hackers?`  in short you can make it more secure but ***never unavailable to hackers***. There's other ways beside just a connection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to protect your connection is to work with SQL Server not directly, but via some basic API.

For example, you have SQL Db, you create some php-based service, which will communicate with internet via some url and commands (https://myapi.com/?showsomething=this&date=...) and with SQL Server - via PDO or sqlsrv or whatever commands. You can enable https connection to API.